# jQuery plugin for Date Time Selection with functionality for relative time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, gwt

Wanted a jQuery plugin for selecting date and time with the following features:

- Having option for relative time, immediately in the selection. Previous 1 hour, previous 2 hours and so on.
- Having an option to select the date simultaneously.

I found a screenshot that fulfills the exact requirement, but I have no clue what plugin it is, what library it is from, etc. I think it's from GWT, but I'm not sure. I have found no similar reference to this on the GWT documentation. If someone can direct me to the what the exact plugin is, or suggest an alternative one that has the same functionality, that would be greatly appreciated.

Image follows
: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/23NzT.jpg

I'm a newbie at this; so sorry if this is on the wrong thread or I overstepped a few known rules of the community.